# What is maximum number of keyword a category can have in tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, keyword

What is the maximum number of keyword a category can have in Tridion 2013 SP1.

Will it be a problem while loading in Tridion in Dropdown.

Comment: Maybe also try changing the list type from dropdown to tree.

Comment: From a practical point, I've noticed it gets harder for authors working with large sets of items sooner than any performance issues. Hundreds of keywords seem reasonable and a few thousand might be okay. But at some point a drop down of several thousand items is too much from just a usability view.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try it. More than likely it will be a limitation of the database rather than Tridion itself, although as you say, the practical limitations are more likely to be how long a list you can load in the GUI. Here's a little powershell snippet that should do it for you. I got up to a couple of thousand before I aborted it on my system.

```
$core = GetTridionCoreClient
$k = $core.GetDefaultData(1024, "tcm:1092-4345-512",$null)
while ($true) {
  $k.Title = ($count++).ToString()
  $core.Create($k, $null)
}
```

Warning: If you run this, it might fill your system up with keywords. Best if you don't add them to a category you can't afford to delete.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official maximum number documented.  It largely depends on the power of the client's machine at the moment, i.e browser, CPU, memory and speed of network connection, and the underlying best-of-breed framework limitations (e.g. WCF Services, .NET Framework, Webkit/browser's javascript engine).

To get the list of keywords populated in a dropdown, Tridion's JavaScript GUI framework makes Ajax requests to the Tridion Core Service.  If the number of Keywords you have exceeds the web service request size, then problems will arise.  If the network is slow, then the list of Keywrods will take a long time to transmit from Tridion's core to the client's browser.  Finally, if the list is too big for the browser to handle, you'll get browser-related memory or CPU intensive issues.

Your best best is to try an experiment in your Tridion users' typical setting, e.g. Windows 7, IE 9 with i5 CPU and 4 GB ram.